# Using global variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple example:

```
server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    uploads = {}
    if (req.url == '/check') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write(JSON.stringify(uploads));
         res.end();
    }
    if (req.url == '/upload') {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.on('fileBegin', function(field, file) {
            var tracker = {file: file, progress: [], ended: false};
            uploads[file.filename] = tracker;
            file.on('progress', function(bytesReceived) {
                tracker.progress.push(bytesReceived);
            })
        });
    };
});
```

Why "check"  return empty uploads ? Should I use global variable in this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with global variables - when a new variable is created in JavaScript without being prefixed by `var`, it is dynamically scoped AFAIK, which means it is global. Anyway, I would feel it better if your variable was indeed declared outside the function for not only *being* global, but for *looking* global too:

```
var uploads = {}
server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/check') {
    // ...
```

Now, let us see your *real* problem: you are using formidable in a very strange way. I, for one, have never used the `on()` method of `formidable.IncomingForm`. I would recommend you to use the `parse()` method, which provides you with a key-value object where the keys are the name of the `<input type="file">` field and the value is the upload file data, such as the path of the file in the server:

```
if (req.url == '/upload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        for (var filename in files) {
          var file = files[filename];
          var tracker = {filename: filename, progress:[], ended:false};
          fs.readFile(file.path, function(err, filecontent) {
            tracker.progress.push(filecontent);
            tracker.ended = true;
          });
          uploads[filename] = tracker;
        }
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        res.write("<A href='/'>ok</a>");
        res.end();

    });
```

`IncomingForm.parse()` will process *all* the files before call the callback. You will have all the files available, and the path to them. Of course, in this example our `tracker.progress` will contain only one bunch of data - which will be the complete file content.

Also, note that the form you will use to upload the file should have the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute:

```
<form action='/upload' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

That is it, hope this helps. Note that I am assuming that you need to solve a problem; if you want to test the `IncomingForm.on()` method, however, this answer will not be much useful. I hope I have made the correct guess :)

Answer (score -1):

`upload` is being set to an empty object(`{}`) on every request, its always going to be `{}`.

Note that the function is called on all requests

Global variable has a special meaning in node.js since all modules has a local scope.
The solution would be to declare it outside of the function.

Like this.

```
var uploads = {};
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   ....
```

I hope this helps